# How can we add dropdown in the data-content field of the popover in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
 <li><a href="#"  data-toggle="popover" title=""data-placement="bottom" data-content="content" role="button" data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="A Title"><b>welcome user</b> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></a></li>
```

How can we add the html lists in the data-content field instead of plain texts[image: default popover]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [Options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage) of Bootstrap's Popover

### HTML

```
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover">popover
</a>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function () {
    $('#example').popover({
        title: "This is a default title",
        html : true,
        content : "<ul><li>test 1</li><li>test 2</li></ul>" 
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: is there way to call the whole class of css which has its own design in this content of popover.